# Make effect that will move attention to web form

Tags: jquery, css, highlighting

I'd like to make some effect that after clicking on a link would visualy highlights the form.

Sofar i got

```
$('#form').addClass("message");
$('#form').animate({backgroundColor: 'ffffff'},3000);
$('#form').animate({opacity:0},3000);
```

and css for it

```
.message{
  background:#9ed0f2;
}
```

The point is just to direct the attention of the user to the form.

Are there some out of the box solutions i should look for?

Comment: onClick you could add a border, change the background color, add a box-shadow, change the background color of the form elements, add a new element which is a picture of a monkey pointing at the form. The choices are endless and it's up to your creatiove brain to choose amd implement what you wnat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could even rumble form http://jackrugile.com/jrumble/ :)

It is better to create highlight or something css class and animate to this class. This way you **separate design** from javascript code.

Check http://jqueryui.com/switchClass/ for demo

Comment: Thanks.This is what i will look further into.

Answer (score 3):

You could actually bring focus to a form element on a link click, highlighting the field as though they had clicked on it.

So example code:

```
$('#link_that_was_clicked').click(function() {
  $('#first_form_element').focus();
});
```

You could also I supposed add a border to the form on the button click so the entire form is surrounded by a 2px black border?

Also you could have jquery scroll to the form when you click the button using jQuery's .scrollTop() and .offet() method

Sample

```
  $('#link_that_was_clicked').click(function() {
      $(document).scrollTop( $("#form").offset().top ); 
      $('#first_form_element').focus();
    });
```

**Links**

[jQuery Focus](http://api.jquery.com/focus/)

[jQuery.scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)

[jQuery.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)